# How do I get the value from HashMap in my ListView?

Tags: android

I've created my own custom adapter by extending `BaseAdapter`. I just want to be able to grab the string of the `value` in my `onItemClick` method (so I can put it as an `intent extra`). How can I do that?

My custom `adapter` looks like this:

```
   private class HashMapAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private HashMap<String, String> mMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private String[] mKeys;
        private Context mContext;

        private HashMapAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, String> map) {
            mContext = context;
            mMap = map;
            mKeys = mMap.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);          
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mMap.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return mMap.get(mKeys[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//          String key = mKeys[position];

            RowView row;
            if(convertView == null) {
                row = new RowView(getBaseContext());
            } else {
                row = (RowView) convertView;
            }
            row.display(mKeys[position]);
            return row;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Calling your `getItem(...)` method doesn't work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I couldn't get it to work before, but this is how to do it:

```
intent.putExtra("url",  arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the getView method you can retrieve the value by using

```
mMap.get(mKeys[position]);
```

although I'm not 1000% sure

Answer (score 0):

Use LinkedHashMap and get value according to position using

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> myCalandersAvailable2
```

In getView

```
String value = (new ArrayList<String>(myCalandersAvailable2
                .get(position).values())).get(position);
```

It Will give you idea how to do.

or use this method to get value according to position from LinkedHashMap

```
public Object getElementAt(LinkedHashMap map, int index) {
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (index-- == 0) {
            return entry.value();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```